# Error loading native library grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll

Tags: asp.net, .net, grpc

I have an ASP.NET web site targeting Framework 4.6.2 where I attempt to use a GRPC service from my controller.  When I attempt to create the Channel, I get an exception:
`"Error loading native library \"C:\\Users\\sstainba\\repos\\location-management-service\\src\\LocationManagement.Web\\bin\\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll\""}`
My project already has a reference to the GRPC, GRPC.Core, GRPC.Auth and GRPC.Tools packages.  And, in fact, the assembly DOES exist at that exact location.  I am at a loss as to why it won't load.  What other things can I try other than adding the reference?

Answer (score 3):

Figure out the problem... Permissions on the bin folder. I temporarily set permissions to give everyone full control and it worked.

Comment: Adding `IIS_IUSRS` to the permission group and giving full controls resolves this error.